# How to set active tab of jquery ui tabs using custom function?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I want to set active tab in jquery ui tabs based on output of a function active_tab(), but active_tab() function do not run when tabs are initialized.

```
function active_tab()
{
    var t = 1;
    // some conditions
    return t;
}

$( "#tabs1" ).tabs({
    active: function(){
        active_tab();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery UI Tabs option for `active` expects a number, `true`, or `false`.

> Which panel is currently open. Multiple types supported:
>
> - Boolean: Setting active to `false` will collapse all panels. This requires the collapsible option to be `true`.
> - Integer: The zero-based index of the panel that is active (open). A negative value selects panels going backward from the last panel.

I would advise the following type of code:

```
function active_tab(tbs, i){
  if(i == undefined){
    i = 0;
  }
  // Add Other Conditions
  tbs.tabs("option", "activate", i);
  return i;
}

$("#tabs1").tabs();

activate_tabs($("#tabs1"), 1);
```

Another method would be:

```
function active_tab(){
  var t = 1;
  // some conditions
  return t;
}

$("#tabs1").tabs();
$("#tabs1").tabs("option", "activate", activate_tab());
```

You can also do the following:

```
$("#tabs1").tabs({
  activate: activate_tab()
});
```